# Microsoft Office 365 Outlook. How to Change Teams-Meeting Join link

Tags: vba, outlook, office365, outlook-addin

I want to create an Outlook Meeting, which references on a Microsoft Teams Team-Channel Meeting.
I am searching for a way to change the link behind the Button you can see in the picture below.

[image]

I Switched to Development Options and found the Fields OnlineMeetingConfLink, SchedulingServiceMeetingOptionsUrl, SchedulingServiceUpdateUrl, SkypeTeamsMeetingETag, SkypeTeamsMeetingUrl, SkypeTeamsProperties.

I already tried to change it by myselfe but it didn't worked.

Dose anybody know how i can change the Meeting link?

Edit:
I didnt used any code. I tried to change it manual in the second screenshot i added. I got there by click on "draw this formular".
[image]

Comment: @braX i added the view i got when i tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to change the link to the generated Teams meeting, it is stored as a regular named property - you can see the property in [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author). The value of the property can be changed using `AppointmentItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty` (the DASL name of the property is shown in the screenshot).

[image: OutlookSpy - IMessage]